# Failed to copy resources: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException

Tags: quarkus

I'm trying to compile and run my Quarkus servlet application. But it keeps getting the following error with quarkus-maven-plugin 0.24.0 and 0.25.0. But it works fine with quarkus-maven-plugin 0.23.2

```
ERROR [io.qua.dev] (vert.x-worker-thread-0) Failed to copy resources: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: D:\quarkus-sample\rest\target\classes\myproperties.properties
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:79)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:269)
        at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:103)
        at java.nio.file.Files.delete(Files.java:1126)
        at io.quarkus.dev.RuntimeUpdatesProcessor.checkForFileChange(RuntimeUpdatesProcessor.java:332)
        at io.quarkus.dev.RuntimeUpdatesProcessor.doScan(RuntimeUpdatesProcessor.java:121)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.deployment.devmode.VertxHotReplacementSetup$1.handle(VertxHotReplacementSetup.java:52)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.deployment.devmode.VertxHotReplacementSetup$1.handle(VertxHotReplacementSetup.java:44)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$executeBlocking$2(ContextImpl.java:316)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it worked with a previous version, there's a good chance it's a bug.

Could you create a GitHub issue in our tracker and provide a reproducer (simple Quarkus app reproducing the issue) and the steps to reproduce it?

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed by Quarkus release 0.26.0. 
Related git hub issue can be found in https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/4697